# Updating data in another window

Tags: swift, macos

My macOs app has a main window and it needs to make additional windows to display more information.

I have created the other WindowController in Storyboard and I can instantiate and display the new windows when needed. My issue is that I'm trying to update the information that will be displayed in each window's TableView.

Although I can reference the property `info : [String]` in each window I thinkthe TableView is being displayed before the information is being updated, so it's not working.

The only other way I have tried to update info on a secondary window I used the prepare for segue but since I'm not making my window with a segue in Storyboard I'm not sure if that's what I should be doing.

Here is the code where I'm instantiating the new windows and trying to update the `info` property:

```
@IBAction func scanBatchesButtonPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {
    guard dayFolder != nil else {
        return
    }
    let newIncomingBatches = scanBatches(atURL: dayFolder, igestedBatches: deviceBatchesIngested)
    if newIncomingBatches.count != 0 {
        var newBatchesList : [IngestBatch] = []
        for batch in newIncomingBatches {
            let newBatch : IngestBatch = IngestBatch()
            newBatch.batchURL = batch
            let types = newBatch.getFileTypes()
            
            var batchesWindowControllers : [NSWindowController] = []
            let bwc : NSWindowController = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(identifier: "BatchReportWindowController") as NSWindowController
            let vc = bwc.contentViewController as? BatchViewController
            vc!.info = types
            bwc.showWindow(self)
            batchesWindowControllers.append(bwc)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the ViewController for the additional windows I'm creating:

```
import Cocoa

class BatchViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    public var info : [String] = ["Default", "Test", "Data"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }
    
    
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return info.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return info[row]
    }
}
```

I have it working by putting a function in my secondary window's ViewController that just updates the property, vs. trying to change it directly.

````
I don't know if this is the preferred way to do it though.
```
    public func updateInfoTableView(withInfo : [String]) {
        info = withInfo
        infoTableView.reloadData()
    }
````

Comment: "Here is the WindowController for the additional windows I'm creating"  How do you create a window controller with `NSViewController` as the super class?

Comment: I meant to write: "Here is the ViewController" for the view in the windows I'm creating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using delegate?

```
@objc protocol MyDelegate {
    func changeTitle(title: String)
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    weak var delegate: SomeDelegate?

    @IBAction func myAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.changeTitle("NewTitle")
    }

}

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController, MyDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: NSButton!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
        let myVc = window!.contentViewController as! ViewController
        myVc.delegate = self

    }

    func changeTitle(title: String) {
        myButton.title = title
    }

}
```